# Emails from unknown sender with attachment

Tags: gmail, login, attachment, hacked

Today my Gmail login activity has shown me that I was twice logged in from a strange place and additionally, I found in my trash label two emails from (unknown sender) with subject 'Attachment' with something attached in it. The weird thing was that those emails seemed to be opened, but I didn't do that, and they were by themselves in my trash bin.
I changed my password, but I got another email of that kind.

Please help me, what should I do?

Comment: Could you give us the IP address of the "strange place"? It might have been some Google internal funniness that you're not supposed to see, especially if the IP addresses were 10., 192.168., etc.

Comment: Is this what you are saying about? Regarding the (`unknown sender`)[https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/gmail/composing-and-sending-messages/m8hQtZKlBW4]